# How to make GNOME Terminal transparent?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

I am using GNOME Terminal but, I am not able to make it transparent. Am I missing some packages?

I am using the latest gnome 3.18, so I dont think its a DUP issue.

[image: the gnome is not getting transparent]

Comment: Not sure but maybe try closing your current terminal and opening a new one?

Comment: I tried that but, its not helping. am I missing any packages?

Comment: What graphics card ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292282 . By report it works of Fedora. I suppose I can test it in Fedora as I normally run Fedora, but am not running gnome at the moment.

Comment: I dont think its a DUP. There he was altleast getting transparent when he opens the about tab. But, for me that doesnt work.

Comment: how to check for which graphic card am I using?